# Nested component as argument in React FC / JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, react-functional-component

I have this structure in React FC typescript:

```
import { BaseLayout } from "./...."
import { MainContent } from "./...."
import { SplitContent } from "./...."
import { VideoFeed } from "./...."
...

<Route path="/foo" element={<BaseLayout ContentComponent={MainContent}/>}
```

That works fine.

However, one of the child component is supposed to be another nested component, and I can't seem to make it work.

```
<Route path="/foo" element={<BaseLayout ContentComponent={MainContent}/>}
```

MainContent takes no props/arguments, but SplitContent expects something like:

```
export function SplitContent({TopContent}: {TopContent: FC}) { ... }
```

(I'm just trying to make it work, obv it'll later take a 2nd bottom component as argument but let's just make it work with one first).

So if I try to just pass the SplitContent as component, not a string, TS complains:

```
<Route path="/foo" element={<BaseLayout ContentComponent={<SplitContent/>}/>}

"Type Element isn not assignable to type FC<{}>"
```

(On top of SplitContent not receiving an expected TopContent argument).

If I suppress it with ts-ignore, then in the console it doesn't render and I get:

```
" React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in component) or a class/function (for composite component) but got: <SplitContent/> "
```

Comment: What does `BaseLayout` do?

Comment: Just basic styling and holding compoments. The base layout can take just a component, but also a component layout that splits into 2 components vertically or horizontally. ANd those require being passed other compoments as their argument, hence my question...

Comment: How about `WrappedComponent={<SomeConcreteComponent />}` ?

Comment: *Then the component doesn't load....* - it means something is wrong with `BaseLayout`

Comment: Okay I'm going to do a few syntax tests & update question with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between a component (a function/class which might have state, and is likely to return some elements) and rendered elements (`<Foo />`). In this case, what you need to provide is a component. Not a rendered element:

```
<Route
  path="/foo"
  element={
    <BaseLayout
      ContentComponent={() => (
        <WrapperComponent WrappedComponent={SomeConcreteComponent} />
      )}
    />
  }
/>
```

notice that

```
() => <WrapperComponent WrappedComponent={SomeConcreteComponent}/>
```

is a component which in turn, renders something. It's not the rendered thing.

I'd suggest not making it in render though, if possible.
Create it outside of your main component as a new component. And use it here. Like:

```
const MyComponent = () => <WrapperComponent WrappedComponent={SomeConcreteComponent}/>;

// And inside your main component
<Route
  path="/foo"
  element={
    <BaseLayout
      ContentComponent={MyComponent}
    />
  }
/>
```

Comment: You're an everyday hero. I wasn't able to make sense of the error message in the console. Now I get it - I didn't know that <Foo/> would end up being a rendered thing, which of course cannot work as we might as way just pass static html instead... Great.

Comment: Glad to hear it was useful. Cheers!